# Punctuation inside of apostrophe in "Rus' "

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

I am doing a research paper on Kievan Rus' (note the apostrophe) a political state of the 10th century. How would I format punctuation with this nation's name?

Option 1 (period outside apostrophe):

> Olaf I was raised in Kievan Rus'.

Option 2 (period inside apostrophe):

> Olaf I was raised in Kievan Rus.'

Comment: @mahmud koya: In this case, the apostrophe doesn't stand for any missing letters. It stands for the last character in Рѹ́сь, the soft sign, which is commonly transliterated by an apostrophe. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sign#Representations).

Comment: Also, I think it's normally _the_ Kievan Rus'.

Comment: A period never comes before an apostrophe. Like, ever. What is this question.

Answer (score 1):

While (depending on how you are typesetting your paper) the character may be encoded the same way as an apostrophe, it is not functionally an apostrophe at all, so I would definitely put the period after.